# Array AngularJs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Good afternoon,
I would like a help to solve a problem with Array in AngularJS . I have a variable that contains an array where I variables with array. I wonder how I can list those variables that have arrays and their data.

```
this.prefix = [
        {
            "E01":[{"name":"Teste01"}],
            "E02":[{"name":"Teste02"}]
        }
    ];
```

I would like to print the prefix and the names associated with each prefix.

Comment: what you're looking for is `ng-repeat`

Comment: Yes, However as I print the E01 , E02.

Comment: you need to loop over the properties in each object in the root array.

Comment: Added code and a fiddle in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have nested properties you are trying to dig out, you can do something like this :

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/70vxado6/14/

```
  <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in prefix">
     <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">{{k}} : {{v[0].name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

You use `(k, v)` in the repeat to access the key or value. I used v index of 0 to get the name because it is an object in an array, but I if that object ever changes, you will need to change how that works. I just used a ul and li for example, you can repeat over whatever you like.

Comment: I need to print the E01 and E02

Comment: @YehudiMikhael I added that with the `{{k}}`, check the answer, right now it will print `E01 : Teste01` and so on

Comment: I will test here and just say here

Comment: @YehudiMikhael just check the fiddle and see for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in prefix">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
for(var obj in this.prefix){
    for(var prop in obj){
        console.log("property name: " + prop + ", property value: " + obj[prop]);
    }
}
```